# How can I adapt my code to be used by different entities?

Tags: java, output

I have started adapting an older part of my code base and realised I had made the mistake of overusing the `System.out.printf()` method. Previously the class would handle commands given by the CLI user who was operating the server, however now I am adding the capability for connecting clients to essentially become administrators (assuming they have been issued with the `admin` status by the initial CLI user). 
In order to save rewriting a lot of my code base I figured the best idea would be to issue certain commands given by the admin clients using the same class/methods as the CLI user (So the client's command has the exact same effect as a CLI user's command and so the client may see the same output a CLI user would).

My problem is the method that I am using for the CLI user's commands over-uses the `printf()` method from `System.out` for command output. How can I adapt this class so that both CLI users and clients may obtain the same output.

**Things to note:**

- `client` refers to a `Socket` connection of user that is connecting remotely and is using a username that is registered with the server.
- The output of some of the methods contain strings that need to be given in "real-time" correspondence to the event; therefore returning the output String from the method would not be suitable in this scenario.
- The following is a *very* rough 'pseudo' copy of the class outlining the issue. I am willing to show people the main class through a GitHub link or similar, but I did not want to initially swamp this question with code.

**Code**

```
    public boolean executeCommand(String[] command) {
        switch (command[0]) {
            case "kill":
                 return kill(command);
            case "clients":
                 if (!clientList.isEmpty())
                    for (String username: clientList.keySet())
                        System.out.printf("%s\t%s\n\n", username, clientList.get(username).getAddress());
                else
                    System.out.println("No clients connected!");
                return true;

            // ...and so on            

            default:
                System.out.printf("\"%s\": command unknown.\n Type \"help\" for a list of commands.\n", command[0]);
         }
    }

    private boolean kill(String[] args) {
        args[1].disconnect(args[2]);
        System.out.printf("Killed %s with reason %s", args[1], args[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `PrintStream` and assign it to `System.out` before you call your legacy code.  All the calls to `System.out` will be written instead to your stream.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, was waiting for other possible answers before selecting one. This seems to do the trick, thanks.